# Extract plot line formula as vector

Tags: r, plot, line, formula

I got data.frame like this:

`V1 V2
-251 1426
-250 1466
-249 1546
-248 1482
-247 1509
-246 1475`
I built linear model like:

```
fit=lm(x1$V2~x1$V1)
```

Then i plot this line

```
lines(x1$V1,fitted(fit),col="red")
```

So, the question is:
Is there any way to extract plotted line as data.frame or as formula f(x)=ax+b? Thanks in advance!
PS Just curious.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't guess this that easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
data.frame(x=x1$V1,y=fitted(fit))
```

If you want to get formula, you can use

```
b=lm$coefficients[1]
a=lm$coefficients[2]
cat("y=",b,"+x*",a)
```